# jquery object extended with identical object

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, extend

So I have a global object called bby_dataset and I am looping through some data and pushing it to bby_dataset with extend. Except that the datasets pushing are always starting at 0. So when I do an extend the second time the first dataset gets overwritten.

```
var bby_dataset = {};
function bby_test(page) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(productTemplate=Printers)?format=json&show=manufacturer,sku,modelNumber,name,regularPrice&pageSize=100&page="+page+"&apiKey={APIKEY}",
    cache: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.totalPages != page){
            $.extend(bby_dataset, data.products);
            bby_test(data.currentPage + 1);
        }else{
            $.extend(bby_dataset, data.products);
            bby_call(bby_dataset);
        }
    }
});
}
bby_test(1);
```

The objects look like the following obj1: {0}, {1}, {2} obj2: {0}, {1}, {2}. So bby_dataset first loop takes in obj1 but when obj2 goes through the data is replaced instead of extended. I can't really show the result.

To be clear I understand that its not working because of the above I'm wondering if there is a way to do like an append to the end that auto changes the names to 3, 4, 5 or something. Otherwise although the first one can simply be added there after you would have to loop through each object and append it as a new object through extend.

Comment: Can you please add your result as well..?

Comment: Edits added to end of post.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question still stands I found my solution in the object itself, i switched it to an array and everything works fine.